# I have monthly data but up the data into specific month and then all the years of that month, how do I return a chronologically ordered dataset?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jupyter

I have a 4d data set, where the first axis is technically month, the second one is all the years for that month, and then the spatial coordinates.
So january (0) has 27 values representing 27 years of january.

My goal is to rebuild the time series so that it's January of year 1, February of year 1... January of year 2, february of year 2, etc. just a normal monthly time series. However my function to reorder the data set is wrong and does not order the right month and year together.

Can someone see what might be wrong with my function? The shape of my new "merged month" array is correct, but it does not reorder the array "data" correctly:

```
# 4d data set, with 12 month, 27 years (so each month [jan - dec] has 27 points):
data = np.random.rand(12,27,281,375)


#function to try and get data back into chronological order (1st month - year 1, 2nd month - year 1...)
def merge_months(split_data):
    merged_months = []
    for month in range(split_data.shape[0]):
        for year in range(split_data.shape[1]): 
            print(month, year)
            merged_months.append(split_data[month][year])
    return merged_months

merged_months = np.array(merge_months(data))

print(merged_months.shape)
(324,281,374)
```

I am expecting from the reordered output to be an array of:

(1st value of january year 1, 2nd value is february year 1, .... 13th value is january year 2, 14th value is february year 2... etc).

someone kindly suggested this:

```
num_years = 27
num_months = 12
height = 281
width = 375

data = np.random.rand(num_months, num_years, height, width)

# The reshape is equivalent to .reshape(num_years * num_months, height, width)
data_ord = np.swapaxes(data, 0, 1).reshape(-1, *data.shape[-2:])

# Check for february, year 5, pixel (34, 34)
month_idx = 1  # february
year_idx = 4  # year 5
height_idx = 34
width_idx = 34

feb5px1 = data[month_idx, year_idx, height_idx, width_idx]
feb5px2 = data_ord[year_idx * num_months + month_idx, height_idx, width_idx]
```

but I would like to apply it to all gridpoints, not just one....

I tried:

```
test = []
num_months = 12

for yr_idx in range(27):
    for month_idx in range(12):
        test.apppend(d[year_idx*num_months+month_idx, :,:])
```

but I get an error saying: 'list' object has no attribute 'apppend'

Comment: Would be good to show the expected DataFrame you want, because would be more easy to us to see the table.

Comment: I added an extra line explaining what the expected output would be. Does that help clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you just need to swap the first two axes, and then flatten them by reshaping, see code below:

```
num_years = 27
num_months = 12
height = 281
width = 375

data = np.random.rand(num_months, num_years, height, width)

# The reshape is equivalent to .reshape(num_years * num_months, height, width)
data_ord = np.swapaxes(data, 0, 1).reshape(-1, *data.shape[-2:])

# Check for february, year 5, pixel (34, 34)
month_idx = 1  # february
year_idx = 4  # year 5
height_idx = 34
width_idx = 34

feb5px1 = data[month_idx, year_idx, height_idx, width_idx]
feb5px2 = data_ord[year_idx * num_months + month_idx, height_idx, width_idx]

assert feb5px1 == feb5px2

# And for all pixels this month
feb5_1 = data[month_idx, year_idx]
feb5_2 = data_ord[year_idx * num_months + month_idx]

assert np.allclose(feb5_1, feb5_2)
```

Comment: `np.swapaxes` does swap two axes: here axes 0 and 1 are swapped, a.k.a the month and year axes, thus month become axis 1 and year become axis 0. `data.shape` returns a tuple with the length of each axis of `data`, `data.shape[-2:]` returns only the 2 last elements of this tuple, i.e. `(height, width)`, the star expansion operator `*` expand the tuple (`.reshape(-1, *(34, 34))` implicitly becomes `.reshape(-1, 34, 34)`). The `-1` in the `.reshape` is to tell numpy to automatically infer the size for this dimension. I put a comment in the code for a more explicit equivalence for the `.reshape`.

Comment: I don't get it, it is already doing the job for all grid points. And with numpy there is almost always a better (more efficient) way than a for loop.

Comment: Ok, I just add an example for this in the post, just in case